# gcc not creating output file

Tags: c, gcc, sublimetext

GCC only sometimes creates output files, and I have no idea why. I have been compiling my files in Sublime Text with this build system:

```
{
"cmd": ["gcc", "$file_name", "-o", "${file_base_name}", "-Wall"],
"selector" : "source.c",
"shell" : false,
"working_dir" : "$file_path"
}
```

GCC runs and gives me any output necessary for debugging, but once I fix the code and there are no errors, no output file is created. I have also tried running `gcc input.c -o output.exe` in the command line. This was all working just a few hours ago, but has seemingly randomly stopped without me changing anything.

Comment: It seems you have a problem with your editor, not gcc. Could you try compiling it using a command-line shell?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about sublime text editor, not about C or gcc as tagged

Comment: @abligh: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) mentions "software tools commonly used by programmers". Sublime is a programmers' editor.

Comment: @milton - The second part of the question mentions that I then tried compiling using the command line and still was not receiving an output file

Comment: I have not used sublime, but given that the `"cmd"` string above seems to construct the compile command `gcc $filename -o ${file_base_name} -Wall` it would appear that if run in the same directory as `$filename`, `-o ${file_base_name}` would attempt to overwrite `$filename` as `basename` generally just strips the leading 'path' from `$filename`. Second, double-check `"working_dir"` as it again suggests that you are working in the same directory as `$filename` which may lead to the problem above. As I said, I don't use sublime, but based on what appear to be shell commands, it makes sense.

Comment: @Hat the bulk of your question appears to be about a sublime text editor configuration. The bit about compiling at the command line gives neither the program you are trying to compile or the error. I suggest you rephrase this as a question as to why a compile from the command line doesn't work, giving some information about what fails and how to replicate it.